# Convert byte[] image to string

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

```
MediaFile ficheiro;
byte[]  image = File.ReadAllBytes(ficheiro.Path);
var file = image.ByteArrayImageToBase64();
string[] x = new string[] { file };
```

MediaFile is a plugin to get image in gallery

Visually the code does not give me error. But I want to see another way that I can convert the bytes of the image to string.

What would be the most efficient way to convert an array of bytes from an image to a string. I intend to send this image later with a post method. But my difficulty is in conversion because trying to send says that the request is too long. due to `ByteArrayImageToBase64`

Comment: why do you need to send the image as string?

Comment: Please edit your post and include the code that is actually raising the exception or throwing the error, and please cut and paste the *actual error message*. That helps us write a better answer and helps others find your post if they have the same question. See [ask].

Comment: because the parameter that receives the image in api is as string [] and I'm just consuming it.

Comment: Are you certain that you need to send the contents of the image as string and not a file path or url?

Comment: Somewhere that "image string" will need to be transformed back into a real image, so you cannot just use any "byte[] to string" conversion, just the one(s) understood by that system